# How does garbage collection affect jetty latencies?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jetty

I have a jetty application processing about 2k requests a second. Machine has 8 cores and JVM heap size is 8GB. There are a lot of memory mapped files and internal caching so that takes up most of the heap space (4.5 GB).

Here are the stats after the application is stable and the JVM is done tuning Young and Old gen spaces:
Young Generation :  2.6GB
Old Generation : 5.4GB

I'm seeing that my young GC is invoked every 3 seconds and the entire Eden space is cleared (i.e. very less data is passed onto old generation). I understand that filling up the Young generation so quickly means I'm allocating way too many objects and that this is an issue. But there is definitely no memory leak in my application, since the servers have been up since 2 weeks with no OOM crashes.

Young GC is a stop the world event. So my understanding is that all threads are paused during this time. So when I monitor latencies from the logs, I can see that every 2-3 seconds about 6-9 requests have a response time of > 100ms (My average response time is < 10 ms). And when Full GC is called, I see that 6-9 reqeusts have a response time of > 3 seconds (That's how long Full GC takes and since it's invoked very very less, it is not an issue here)

My question is since my jetty application has a 200 size threadpool and no bounded request queue, shouldn't calling young GC have an accordion effect on my response times? Will a 100 ms buffer be added to all the requests in my queue?

If so, what is the best way to measure response times from being added to the queue to the output response? Because the 6-9 request thing I mentioned above is from checking the logs. So basically, when the application logic is invoked to just before the response is sent, I maintain start and end time variables and subtract these 2 and dump it to the logs.

One way would be to check my load balancer. But since these servers are behind an ELB, I don't really have much access here other than average response times which don't really help me.

Answer (score -1):

You should enable GC logging for your application. Try adding following jvm command line arguments

`-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:-PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCCause -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=<REPLACE_ME> -XX:GCLogFileSize=20M -Xloggc:<path_to_gc_log_dir>/gc.log`

Then look at the events in GC logs and try to correlate it with application logs